# java always press enter key in for loops

Tags: java, for-loop

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter how much array names  : ");
        int number = input.nextInt();
        

        String[] names = new String[number];

        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            System.out.print((i) + ". next index :");
            names[i] = input.nextLine();
            input.nextLine();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(names[i]);

        }

    }
}
```

mine software is working but in console have so much empty places .

I want to create as many rows as the number the user enters and give a value to each row.